# Adding custom comparator for integer sorting in Nattable

Tags: nattable

I tried sorting header layers, which is working fine for Text but not for Integers and dates - so I want to create a custom comparator for that.

Comment: Can you post a minimum, complete, verifiable example of the code you used to attempt to sort header layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a comment on your issue. Sorting of Numbers and Dates is working pretty fine in NatTable. In fact the sorting of all `Comparable` data types is working fine with the `DefaultComparator` applied by the `DefaultSortConfiguration`. But to make it work correctly, you need to register the according data type converters as shown in various NatTable examples. Without the converter all data in NatTable is treated as String, which results in "incorrect" sorting.

Second to your question. You can register a custom comparator like this:

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
    SortConfigAttributes.SORT_COMPARATOR,
    new MyCustomComparator(),
    DisplayMode.NORMAL,
    CUSTOM_COMPARATOR_LABEL);
```

So you need to register a `Comparator` for the configuration attribute `SortConfigAttributes.SORT_COMPARATOR` and an according label.

But if you do not have a matching type converter, you will need to compare Strings. So IMHO you need to register a `DisplayConverter` and sorting works as intended without the need for a custom comparator.

Comment: Where i can register Data Type ?

Comment: You register an IDisplayConverter via ConfigRegistry as most of the configurations in NatTable. Have a look at the documentation for further information https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=editing